# How come Google Maps isn't available to App Store accounts from Israel?

Tags: ios-appstore, google-maps

When I browse to [Google Apps for iPhone](http://www.google.com/mobile/iphone) with my iPhone and click on Google Maps, I'm redirected to the App Store but receive the following note:

> Your request could not be completed. The item you've requested is not
>   currently available in the Israeli Store, but it is available in the
>   U.S. Store. Tap Change Store to view this item.

When I click `Change Store`, I get:

> Cannot connect to iTunes Store

How come?

Comment: You should contact a Google representative for answers. No one here will be able to provide you with a valid answer. Only Google truly knows why.

Comment: I think the OP is asking why the error occurs when changing stores, not why Google choose to not put an app in the Israeli store.

Comment: @stuffe, wouldn't it be an App store link when he clicks on Google Maps in the Google Apps app? It seems like the Google Apps app wouldn't discriminate the apps it shows to users even if they weren't available. As a result, it would make sense to me that the link would be intact but the destination would fail. I know there is street view in Israel and maps, but it almost seems like Google has chosen not to release an "Israeli" version of Google Maps app (language issues, perhaps?). Or am I missing something completely?

Comment: @stuffe, if you look at his comment in the answer below, he asks why it's not in the store. That's why I posted my comment.

Answer (score 2):

Your apple ID is registered in the Israeli Store. The application is not available in the Israeli Store, so you cannot switch to the U.S. store.

Two items need to happen for an App to be listed in a certain country:

1. The developer of the app (Google in this case) needs to register with Apple to fulfill all the legal and contractual requirements to sell in each country they choose to have a presence for any of their apps to be sold.
2. They need to submit and have Apple approve each specific app for each specific country. Most developers push all apps to all eligible stores, but they don't have to choose to do that even though they could opt to do that.

Let's leave the speculation on who / what / why to either company (Apple and Google) to address in particular, but we can certainly discuss the mechanics of how the app stores work without getting into opinion and conjecture.

Comment: Why is it not available in the Israeli store?

Comment: likely it is due to license restriction.

Comment: I think Google forgot to press the Button. Google Maps for iOS is also not available in Pakistan. However Android version is available since its launch...